# How are FFTs different from DFTs and how would one go about implementing them in C++?

Tags: c++, fft

After some studying, I created a small app that calculates DFTs (Discrete Fourier Transformations) from some input. It works well enough, but it is quite slow.

I read that FFTs (Fast Fourier Transformations) allow quicker calculations, but how are they different? And more importantly, how would I go about implementing them in C++?

Comment: FFT is just a way of referring to algorithms that quickly calculate DFTs; that is, the result of an FFT algorithm should be the same (or very close to) the result from just calculating the DFT by the definition.

Comment: FFT can only be calculated on a sample that is a power of 2 in length, DFT has no such restriction. I didn't see that in anybody's answer, but it's something you need to know and I didn't think it warranted a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to manually implement the algorithm, you could take a look at the [Fastest Fourier Transform in the West](http://www.fftw.org/)

Even thought it's developed in C, it officially works in C++ (from the [FAQ](http://www.fftw.org/faq/))

> Question 2.9. Can I call FFTW from
>   C++?
>
> Most definitely. FFTW should compile
>   and/or link under any C++ compiler.
>   Moreover, it is likely that the C++
>    template class is
>   bit-compatible with FFTW's
>   complex-number format (see the FFTW
>   manual for more details).

Comment: Hmmm... the library you mentioned requires a fee for non-commercial use.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't know this was for commercial purposes. In that case, you could try http://kissfft.sourceforge.net/ . This uses the BSD license

Answer (score 3):

FFT has n*log(n) compexity compared to DFT which has n^2.

There are lot of literature about that, and I strongly advise that you check that first, because such wide topic can not be full explaned here.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform (check external links )

If you need library I advise you to use existing one, for instance.
http://www.fftw.org/
This library has efficiently implementation of FFT and is also used in propariaretery software (MATLAB for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Steven Smith's book [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com) , specifically [Chapter 8 on the DFT](http://www.dspguide.com/ch8.htm) and [Chapter 12 on the FFT](http://www.dspguide.com/ch12.htm), does a much better job of explaining the two transforms that I ever could.

By the way, the whole book is available for free (link above) and it's a very good introduction to signal processing.

Regarding the C++ code request, I've only used the Fastest Fourier Transform in the West (already cited by superexsl) or DSP libraries such as those from TI or Analog Devices.

Answer (score 1):

The results of a correctly implemented DFT are essentially identical to the results of a correctly implemented FFT (they differ only by rounding errors).  As others have pointed out here, the major difference is that of performance.  DFT has O(n^2) operations while the FFT has O(nlogn) operations.

The best, most readable publication I have ever found (the one I still refer to) is [The Fast Fourier Transform and its Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133075052) by E Oran Brigham.  The first few chapters provide a very thorough overview of the continuous and discrete forms of the Fourier Transform.  He then uses that to develop the fast version of the DFT based on the [Cooley-Tukey Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) for the radix-2 (n is a power of 2) and mixed-radix cases (though the latter being somewhat more shallow treatise than the former).

The basic approach in the radix-2 algorithm to perform a linear time operation on the input X and to recursively split the result in half and perform a similar linear time operation on the two halves.  The mixed radix case is similar, though you need to divide X into equal portions each time, so it helps if n doesn't have any large prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this nice explanation with some algorithms described.

[FastFourierTransform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FastFourierTransform.html)

About implementation,

- first i'd make sure your implementation returns correct results (compare the output from matlab or octave - which have built in fourier transformates)
- optimize when necessary, use profilers
- don't use unnecesary for loops